# In my Android project using Firebase I get this warning: W / System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am doing a project with Java in Android Studio. I made a user login page. I want it to redirect to the home page after the user name is entered, but I get a warning like W / System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. The emulator's WiFi is also on.
In the Firebase Authentication section, users are authorized to register with email and password.

Code:

```
    public MainActivity() {
    }

 

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      
        Button btngiris=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button btnkayit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.kayit);
        girisyetkisi=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        txtadi=findViewById(R.id.txtadi);
        txtemaili=findViewById(R.id.txtemaili);
        txtsifresi=findViewById(R.id.txtsifresi);

        btnkayit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,kayitol.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        });

        btngiris.setOnClickListener( v -> {
            String str_ad = txtadi.getText().toString();
            String str_email=txtemaili.getText().toString();
            String str_sifre=txtsifresi.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(str_ad  )){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"İsim girilmesi gerekir",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(str_email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email girilmesi gerekir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str_sifre)){

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Şifre  girilmesi gerekir",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            else{
                girisyetkisi.signInWithEmailAndPassword(str_email,str_sifre).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, task -> {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        DatabaseReference yolGiris= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Kullanıcılar").child(girisyetkisi.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        yolGiris.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MenusayfasiActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Giriş başarısız",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue using wifi on a physical device. But on a device with cell service turned on, I do not see the warning. What happens if you use cell data?

Answer (score 0):

dependencies {
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: fix in build.gradle